# How do I create a permanent snapshot of a Time Machine backup

Tags: backup, time-machine

I did a clean install of my Mac and continued to use my same Time Machine drive. I want to preserve the last backup before I did a clean install, but Time Machine will delete old backups as the drive gets full.

How can I copy a backup without worrying it will be deleted?

My first guess was to just perform a copy, but I'm not sure this will work due to the structure of a Time Machine backup.

Comment: Do you have a seperate drive that can be fully used for storing this copy? - Or do you want to store the copy on the same drive as the original?

Comment: @jksoegaard I am using my same external drive. It's fairly large, so a single snapshot won't be a big deal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've decided to use rsync to create an archive copy. [This website](http://icanhelpyourmac.com/tip_archive/understanding_apples_time_machine/index.html) also mentions hard links so I believe a rsync archive will be fine.

I'm using this command:

`rsync -vahW [source] [target]`

This [SO](https://serverfault.com/questions/386657/optimizing-rsync-for-transferring-huge-files-quickly) mentions -W is best to speed up local network copies, plus I'm doing a new copy so no need for diffing.